# Yfinance Pandas picking raw or fmt values

Tags: python, yfinance

Trying to get the a field on Yahoo Finance Page (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UTIL.L?p=UTIL.L)

In View-source of that webpage, this field is showing as `annualReportExpenseRatio":{"raw":0.003,"fmt":"0.30%"},`

My need is to get this annualReportExpenseRatio value (either raw as 0.003 or fmt as 0.30% is fine to pick)

Am using the standard yfinance module on Jupyter as follows:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
....
blah blah blah
....
a.append(stock.info.get('annualReportExpenseRatio[fmt]'))
```

But the problem is that irrespective of using "raw" or "fmat", it is not picking/returning the 0.003 or 0.30% value. It is returning a blank or null value.

So essentially, the question is - what should I use/change at `a.append(stock.info.get('annualReportExpenseRatio[fmt]'))` line using which I can get either the raw or the fmt value?

What am I missing here, please?

Comment: "it is not picking/returning the 0.003 or 0.30% value" - what _is_ it returning?

Comment: @ForceBru It is returning blank.